Background location updates stops working in main project
I have a pod that uses background location to track the user running activity. When I use the pod project directly, it does the tracking in background without any problem, but when I install the pod into another project, the background location last for about 50 seconds until it stops getting updates. I use the same config in Xcode and the same permissions.
Location permissions in .plist file:
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>The application needs to know your location to locate your photos and each point of the race in live.</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>The application needs to know your location to locate each point of the race in live.</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>The application needs to know your location when uploading the photo to locate it at each point of the race.</string>

My LocationManager config:
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
self.locationManager.activityType = .fitness
self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
self.locationManager.showsBackgroundLocationIndicator = true
self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true

I have location updates active in background modes.

Do you have a Timer in the other project? Timer seems to be the usual culprit even of they aren't related

Yes, I have a timer to display the time passed, but I already tried removing the timer and the same thing happens.

I finally found the culprit. I am using a Lottie animation the screen before the location activity begins, I found that if I hide the Lottie view when pushing to the next screen the background location works fine. Maybe the Lottie library has some kind of process that kill the app after some time.
